# Filtering yfinance data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, yfinance

I am trying to test stock algorithms using historical data, I want to be able to select a date range or even just a date. But I keep getting empty dataframes. What am I not doing right?

All I want it to do is select that day's market data.

here is the relevant code:

```
def getdata(symbol,end_date,days):
    start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days= days)
    return pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date)

today = datetime.date.today()
date = today - datetime.timedelta(days=3)


df = getdata("MLM",today,375)
print(date)
df2 = df.loc[df.index == date]
print(df2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it works like this, but you can select a date from `df` like this: `s = df.loc[date.strftime('%Y%m%d')]`.

Comment: try this:`df2 = df.loc[df.index == date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]`